# Peewee - invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' when looping over query

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, peewee

I'm trying to loop over a Peewee query object and I am getting the following error when I attempt to visit the template where the query is looped over:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

You'll see below the full traceback and code for both the view function and template. I've even tried simplifying down the template loop to just:

```
{% for company in companies %} 
    <p>{{ company.company_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and I still get the same error.

**Full Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 758, in decorated_view
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/wyssuser/Desktop/all_my_projects/new_danish/app/views.py", line 143, in index
  return render_template('new_batch.html', companies=companies)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
  context, ctx.app)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
  rv = template.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
  return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/wyssuser/Desktop/all_my_projects/new_danish/app/templates/new_batch.html", line 2, in top-level template code
  {% extends "base.html" %}
File "/Users/wyssuser/Desktop/all_my_projects/new_danish/app/templates/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
  {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
  {% block doc -%}
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 4, in block "doc"
  {%- block html %}
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 20, in block "html"
  {% block body -%}
File "/Users/wyssuser/Desktop/all_my_projects/new_danish/app/templates/base.html", line 95, in block "body"
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
File "/Users/wyssuser/Desktop/all_my_projects/new_danish/app/templates/new_batch.html", line 30, in block "content"
  {% for company in companies %}
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1772, in next
  obj = self.iterate()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1760, in iterate
  return self.process_row(row)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1833, in process_row
  setattr(instance, column, func(row[i]))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 735, in python_value
  return value if value is None else self.coerce(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**View code**

```
@app.route('/', methods=("POST", 'GET'))
@login_required
def index():
  form = GetClientsForm()

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    if form.sectors.data == 'Realtors':
      companies = Realtor.select().where((Realtor.have_contacted != True) & (Realtor.dont_contact_anymore != True))
      return render_template('new_batch.html', companies=companies)

    else: #Biotech/Engineering
      companies = Company.select().where((Company.have_contacted != True) & (Company.dont_contact_anymore != True))
      return render_template('new_batch.html', companies=companies)
```

**Template code**

```
...
{% for company in companies %}
    <tr class="company-row {{ company.id }}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ company.id }}-info" id="row-{{ company.id }}" data-company-id="{{ company.id }}">
      <td class="col-md-3 company-name">
        <input type="text" value="{{ company.company_name }}" id="{{ company.id }}-company-name" class="form-control" name="company-name">
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-2 company-website">
        <div>
          <a href="{{ company.website }}" target="blank_">{{ company.website }}</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-3 company-email">
        <input type="text" value="{{ company.email_address }}" id="{{ company.id }}-company-email" class="form-control" name="company-email">
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1 company-contact-form">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="{{ company.id }}-contact-form" name="contact-form" data-url='contact_form_company'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1 contact-company">
        {{ render_submit('E-mail', class="contact-button", data='data-url=contact_company') }}
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1 remove-company">
        {{ render_submit("Don't Contact", class="dont-contact-button", data='data-url=dont_contact_company') }}
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-1 company-page">
        <div>
          <a href="{{ url_for('company_page', company_id=company.id) }}">{{ render_submit('Company Page') }}</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

**Update** - model code

```
class Company(Model):
  dont_contact_anymore = BooleanField(default=False)
  company_name = CharField()
  website = CharField(unique=True)
  email_address = CharField()
  country = CharField()
  scraped_on = DateTimeField(formats="%m-%d-%Y")
  have_contacted = BooleanField(default=False)
  current_pipeline_phase = IntegerField(default=0)

  day_0_message_id = IntegerField()
  day_0_contacted_by = ForeignKeyField(
    rel_model=User,
    related_name='contacted_by_day_0',
    db_column='day_0_contacted_by'
    )
  day_0_emails_contacted = CharField()
  day_0_response = IntegerField()
  day_0_sent = DateTimeField(formats="%m-%d-%Y")

  day_5_message_id = IntegerField()
  day_5_contacted_by = ForeignKeyField(
    rel_model=User,
    related_name='contacted_by_day_5',
    db_column='day_5_contacted_by'
    )
  day_5_emails_contacted = CharField()
  day_5_response = IntegerField()
  day_5_sent = DateTimeField(formats="%m-%d-%Y")

  day_35_message_id = IntegerField()
  day_35_contacted_by = ForeignKeyField(
    rel_model=User,
    related_name='contacted_by_day_35',
    db_column='day_35_contacted_by'
    )
  day_35_emails_contacted = CharField()
  day_35_response = IntegerField()
  day_35_sent = DateTimeField(formats="%m-%d-%Y")

  day_125_message_id = IntegerField()
  day_125_contacted_by = ForeignKeyField(
    rel_model=User,
    related_name='contacted_by_day_125',
    db_column='day_125_contacted_by'
    )
  day_125_emails_contacted = CharField()
  day_125_response = IntegerField()
  day_125_sent = DateTimeField(formats="%m-%d-%Y")

  batch = IntegerField()
  sector = CharField()

  class Meta:
    database = DATABASE
    order_by = ('have_contacted',)

  @classmethod
  def create_company(cls, company_name, website, email_address):
    try:
      with DATABASE.transaction():
        cls.create(company_name=company_name, website=website, email_address=email_address, scraped_on=datetime.now)
        print 'Saved {}'.format(company_name)
    except IntegrityError:
      print '{} already exists in the database'.format(company_name)
```

Comment: Can you show us the model that you're using for `Company`?

Comment: @ezig see update above, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have an `IntegerField` declared on your model, but there is an empty string stored in the database. Perhaps you can go clean up your database:

```
UPDATE whatever SET int_field = NULL WHERE int_field = '';
```